# Parent child tables. Parent with just one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Entity table which has two child tables Person and Organization. This is to say an entity can be an individual or an organization. And the 'entity' itself can have multiple roles.

Roles table. 3 columns:

```
RoleID - int identity (PK)
Name - varchar
Desc - Varchar
```

Entity table. 1 column:

```
EntityId - int identity (PK)
```

EntityRole table. 2 columns (One person can have multiple roles)

```
EntityId - int
RoleId - int
(Composite primary key)
```

PersonEntity

```
  PersonEntityId - identity - primarykey
  EntityID - ForeignKey to Entity.EntityId
  FName, LName - varchar
```

OrgEntity

```
OrgEntityId - identity - primarykey
EntityID - ForeignKey to Entity.EntityId
OrgName - varchar
```

My question is having just EntityId one column in that table a bad design? There are no attributes that the person and org share. They have address but both person and org can have multiple addresses so address is a separate table with (0 to many) between Entity and Address.

Comment: Can more than one Entity have the same Role?

Comment: Yes. Entities are people or organization. So there could be multiple people doing a particular role. In fact roles are limited. 3 is what we know of currently. And we are talking about 600,000 people and about 6000 organizations. Roles can grow.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the "entity" table because you want to avoid using a 3 col compound primary key {Person, Role, Org}. Is that correct? Does it work like this: a person could have multiple roles for an org. A person could hold the same role for multiple orgs. A role could have multiple people for the same org. If so, then your design dictates that a 3 col compound key is warranted.

Comment: It is convoluted I agree. Entity can either be a person or an organization. And entity (read person or organization) can have multiple roles. Person and Org don't have to anything with each other, they are separate entities. Its either a person or an organization. I don't care about people working for an org. at all. So entity is kind of like THE parent and person / org are its children.

Comment: Just a thought, can you combine PersonEntity and OrgEntity into one table and call it Entity (columns EntityId, Name, and type)? The information in the two tables is extremely similar and if all you are trying to do is keep straight what type of entity it is, you can still record that. Plus, then your system will be structured to handle the situation where 6 months after deployment another entity(alien) needs to be added. Also, you would then have just one EntityId that you can use to search for info. As it is, many of your queries will need to use unions in order to query both entity tables.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason I want them as separate entities is that we are going to master them and I don't want to combine person and their organization in a single table.